# Android via NFC IsoDep(ISO14443-4) communication with chip's FIFO cache area no way to more than 12 bytes

Tags: android, caching, nfc, fifo

I'm pretty troubled with android NFC transacting with chip's FIFO cache area. Another side(B) and android app(A): B was electrify to chip,and B write data to chip's FIFO cache area by C language. The chip's FIFO cache area can not save data after outage, and when chip's FIFO cache area send all data, the chip's FIFO cache area will clear.

---

The situation is, A close to chip, send a APDU command, now chip receives the command and produces a signal. Then, the B detects the chip's signal, and grabs the command, then, B gets the command's first byte(fb), more then, B write `[fb+data+9000]` to chip's FIFO cache area. Finally, the transaction of send data back to A manage with chip self and we don't know the chip how to manage the send back.

---

The problem is, when B's write `[fb+data+9000]` less than 15 bytes(means data only 12 bytes), A can receive the `[fb+data+9000]` from chip. But the `[fb+data+9000]` more than 15 bytes, A throws `TagLostException`.

The chip use `ISO14443-4` protocol.

---

The command: [image]

---

The transact code:
`

```
try {
        isoDep.close();
        isoDep.connect();
    }catch (IOException e){
         errorfound = true;
        onMessageReceived.onError(e);
    }
if (!errorfound) {
    if (isoDep.isConnected()) {
        try {
            isoDep.setTimeout(1200);
            response = isoDep.transceive(newtest1_apdu);
            int status = ((0xff & response[response.length - 2]) << 8) | (0xff & response[response.length - 1]);
            if (status != 0x9000) {
                log.error("retrieve data ,read failure");
            }else {
                log.info("retrieve data, result=" + numeralParse.toReversedHex(response));
            }
            onMessageReceived.onMessage(response);
            }
        catch (TagLostException e) {
            log.info("catch tag lost exception, tag isConnected=" + isoDep.isConnected());
            onMessageReceived.onError(e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("catch IOException, isoDep isConnected=" + isoDep.isConnected());
            onMessageReceived.onError(e);
        }
    }else {
        log.error("isoDep not connect");
    }
}
```

`

---

Android app(A) try to a variety of commands, contains this format: [image].

And another side(B) only gets first byte in command and write `[fb+data+9000]` to chip's FIFO cache area. this isn't timeout reason, except `setTimeOut(1200)`, also try `setTimeOut(5000)` or not `setTimeOut`. Other, A and B were not appoint the APDU command specific meaning. Other, by different APDU command, A work well with read Public transportation card(may be this read to block area, and now work with cache area, both work way not same). Other, the configuration of chip is basic default. Other, with other card reader test, chip's send data out success.

---

I go to Google,Bing,Baidu,Android office issues,stackoverflow and so on to search answer, but cannot find. This problem very bothered us. Apologetic with my poor English. Please help, extremely thank you.

(the chip is FM11NC08.)

**New progress,** We found, giving up using APDU command, if A send 1 byte, A can receive maximum 16 bytes. And if A send 2 bytes, A can receive maximum 15 bytes. And if A send 15 bytes, A can receive maximum 2 bytes. The chip's FIFO cache area has 32 bytes space. After B receive A's data, B will clear FIFO cache area, then write data to FIFO cache area.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, B changes the chip's communication rate(from 1M to 2M) and a part of codes. Then A work well with chip! So, we found the communication rate has an impact on NFC communication. If you have the same trouble with NFC communication, might to try our way!

Thanks for people who consider this problem in not-solve days.